# Regex to find duplicate characters ignoring line breaks (Notepad++)

Tags: regex, notepad++

I use the expression

```
(.)\1+
```

to find duplicate characters in a text file using Notepad++.

However, this expression does not work for duplicate characters across two lines:

```
abc
cba
```

What's the best way to find duplicate characters ignoring line breaks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `(.)\1+` does not match `c\nc` because there is a newline in between.

What you want to match is a chunk of identical chars, that may be separated with a line break sequence:

```
(.)(?:\R?\1)+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NW05vP/1).

**Details**

- `(.)` - Capturing group 1 matching any single char other than line break chars
- `(?:\R?\1)+` - 1 or more sequences of:

  - `\R?` - an optional line break sequence (CRLF, LF, CR, or even some Unicode line breaks like `NEL`)
  - `\1` - the same char as captured into Group 1.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
(.)\r?\n?\1+
```

Answer (score 0):

You could match zero or more times a line break `(?:\r?\n|\r)*` between `(.)` and `\1+` or use a questionmark instead of the asterix to make it optional.

`(.)(?:\r?\n|\r)*\1+`